# How to count occurence of each value in array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a database of ISSUES in MongoDB, some of the issues have comments, which is an array; each comments has a writer. How can I count the number of comments each writer has written?

I've tried

```
db.test.issues.group(
{
    key = "comments.username":true;
    initial: {sum:0},
    reduce: function(doc, prev) {prev.sum +=1},
    }
);
```

but no luck :(

A Sample:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50f48c179b04562c3ce2ce73"),
        "project" : "Ruby Driver",
        "key" : "RUBY-505",
        "title" : "GETMORE is sent to wrong server if an intervening query unpins the connection",
        "description" : "I've opened a pull request with a failing test case demonstrating the bug here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/pull/134\nExcerpting that commit message, the issue is: If we do a secondary read that is large enough to require sending a GETMORE, and then do another query before the GETMORE, the secondary connection gets unpinned, and the GETMORE gets sent to the wrong server, resulting in CURSOR_NOT_FOUND, even though the cursor still exis ts on the server that was initially queried.",
        "status" : "Open",
        "components" : [
                "Replica Set"
        ],
        "affected_versions" : [
                "1.7.0"
        ],
        "type" : "Bug",
        "reporter" : "Nelson Elhage",
        "priority" : "major",
        "assignee" : "Tyler Brock",
        "resolution" : "Unresolved",
        "reported_on" : ISODate("2012-11-17T20:30:00Z"),
        "votes" : 3,
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "username" : "Nelson Elhage",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-11-17T20:30:00Z"),
                        "body" : "Thinking some more"
                },
                {
                        "username" : "Brandon Black",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-11-18T20:30:00Z"),
                        "body" : "Adding some findings of mine to this ticket."
                },
                {
                        "username" : "Nelson Elhage",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-11-18T20:30:00Z"),
                        "body" : "I think I tracked down the 1.9 dependency."
                },
                {
                        "username" : "Nelson Elhage",
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-11-18T20:30:00Z"),
                        "body" : "Forgot to include a link"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces on the `key` value and you need to terminate that line with a `,` instead of a `;`.

```js
db.issues.group({
    key: {"comments.username":true},
    initial: {sum:0},
    reduce: function(doc, prev) {prev.sum +=1},
});
```

**UPDATE**

After realizing `comments` is an array...you'd need to use `aggregate` for that so that you can 'unwind' `comments` and then group on it:

```js
db.issues.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$comments'},
    {$group: {_id: '$comments.username', sum: {$sum: 1}}}
);
```

For the sample doc in the question, this outputs:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "Brandon Black",
      "sum": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "Nelson Elhage",
      "sum": 3
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Still has error:SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):2

Comment: @Ace Replace the `=` after `key` with a `:`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Johnny! That solved the problem, but the result is still not alright!!
It didn't recognize the "comments.username" as the result is as :
[ { "comments.username" : null, "sum" : 12 } ]
Which 12 is the total number of records!

Comment: @Ace My bad, I was thinking `comments` was an embedded object, not an array.  You'll need to use `aggregate` for that; see updated answer.

Comment: Nope! Still faulty! :(
`{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }`

Comment: @Ace It's working for my guess at what your docs look like.  Can you edit your question to include an example doc from the `issues` collection?

Comment: Sure,
`_id:...
project:...
key:...
title:...
desc:...
status:...
components:[RSet],[Zset],
comments: [{username:a, body:...}, {username:b, body...}]}`

Comment: @Ace Not in a comment.  Edit your question to include a complete example doc so I can copy and paste it into an `insert` command in the shell.

Comment: Yes! Very much! `mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.2`

Comment: OK! Found the problem, the domain is `db.test.issues`

Answer (score 1):

Just a snide answer here to compliment @JohnnyHKs answer: it sounds like your new to MongoDB and as such possibly working on a new version of MongoDB if that is the case (if not I would upgrade) either way the old `group` count is kinda bad. It won't, for one, work with sharding.

Instead in MongoDB 2.2 you can just do:

```
db.col.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$comments.username", count: {$sum: 1}}})
```

Or something similar. You can read more about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/