# Get frequency for multiple elements in all documents inside a collection mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

So heres my problem.

I am new to mongodb and have a collection which documents are saved like this:

```
{
 "_id": {
    "$oid": "60626db173b4ca321c02ee3e"
 },
 "year": "2021",
 "name": "Book 1",
 "authors": ["Joe, B", "Jessica, K"],
 "createdAt": {
     "$date": "2021-03-30T00:15:45.859Z"
 }
},
{
 "_id": {
    "$oid": "60626db173b4ca321c02ee4e"
 },
 "year": "2021",
 "authors": ["Carl, B", "Jessica, K"],
 "name": "Book 2"
 "createdAt": {
     "$date": "2021-03-30T00:15:45.859Z"
 }
},
```

I need to get both the frequency of all authors and the years of the books.

The expected result would be something like this (as long as i can get each element frequency it doesn't really matter how the results are returned):

```
{
  "authors": {
     "Joe, B": 1,
     "Carl, B": 1,
     "Jessica, K": 2
  },
  "year": {
     "2021": 2
  }
}
```

I've seen this thread [How to count occurence of each value in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319616/how-to-count-occurence-of-each-value-in-array) which does the job in one array but i have no idea if its possible to adapt to get the frequency of multiple elements (year, authors) at the same time or how to do it.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/95JtQEThxvV

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by year [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) authors into the array get [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) count of the year occurrence, [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) into individuals documents.

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by authors and get [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) count of the author occurrence

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by null to combine all documents,  use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to push unique values and convert [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to get final output in [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

[$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { year: "$year" },
      authors: { $push: "$authors" },
      yearCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$authors" },
  { $unwind: "$authors"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { author: "$authors" },
      year: { $first: "$_id.year" },
      yearCount: { $first: "$yearCount" },
      authors: { $push: "$authors" },
      authorCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      years: {
        $addToSet: { k: "$year", v: "$yearCount" }
      },
      authors: {
        $addToSet: { k: "$_id.author", v: "$authorCount" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      years: { $arrayToObject: "$years" },
      authors: { $arrayToObject: "$authors" }
    }
  }
])
```

Demo 2 - For author count grouped by year- https://mongoplayground.net/p/_elnjmknroF

Comment: @jay2p depends on how big a dataset you've, if your data is small DB query is better, but if you have got a huge dataset you should do some calculations in DB and the rest of it code.

Comment: This is great, demo 1 is what i've been looking for! Now i only need to adapt it to like 10 fields :) ! But out of curiosity, performance wise, lets say i have to get the frequency of not two (year and authors in this exameple), but 10 different things (year, authors, publishers and so on), would be better to do it one by one or do a big query? Do you have any idea which would be faster? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: i see. makes sense. Thank you again.